# Solve $\int x\csc^2(3x)\,dx$ by integration by parts

Tags: calculus

> $$\int x\csc^2(3x)\,dx$$

I'm studying integration by parts, and I tried to solve the above integral and I want to know why the $\ln$ function appears in the answer.

My attempt

$uv - \int v\,dv$

$u = x$ $\ \ \ \  $ $dv = \csc^2(3x)$

$du = dx$ $\ \ $ $v = \frac{-\cot(3x)}{3}$

plug the values in the formula I get

$$x\Big(\frac{-\cot(3x)}{3}\Big)-\int \frac{-\cot(3x)}{3}\,dx$$
$$x\Big(\frac{-\cot(3x)}{3}\Big)+\frac{1}{3}\int \cot(3x)\,dx$$
$$\Big(\frac{-\cot(3x)x}{3}\Big)+\frac{(-\csc(3x))}{9}+c$$

the right answer is this, but I don't know why this is the answer,

$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\sin\left(3x\right)\right|\right)-3x\cot\left(3x\right)}{9}+C$

Comment: Recheck $\int \cot(3x) \ dx.$ It is not $-\csc(3x).$ Hint: rewrite as $\int \frac{\cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)} \ dx $

Comment: @VivekKaushik What method should I use  to solve$ \int \frac{\cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)} \ dx$ ?

Comment: Have you learned $u$ substitution ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik yes, I'l try.

Comment: @VivekKaushik could you please show how to solve $\int \frac{\cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)} \ dx$ this is not as easy as the problems I was solving.

Comment: Pose $u= sin(3x)$ then $\frac {du}{dx} =3cos(3x)$ then simplify you can do it...

Comment: @isham I'm not aware about the use of the ln function to solve this as seen in the answer. But I'm stuck here. $\int \frac{cos(3x)}{sin(3x)}$

 $\int\cos(3x)sin(3x)^{-1}$
$u = sin(3x)$ $du=cos(3x)dx$

$\int u^{-1} du \implies \frac{sin(3x)^0}{0}$

Comment: @hjx I posted an answer... note that $\int \frac {du} u = \ln(u)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that cotangent and tangent functions are simple to integrate

$\int \cot(3x)\,dx=\int \frac {\cos(3x)}{ \sin(3x) }dx$

Pose $ u = \sin(3x)$ and $ \frac {du}{dx} =  3 \cos(3x) \iff dx= \frac {du}{3\cos(3x)}$

Then,

$$\int \frac {\cos(3x)} { \sin(3x)} dx= \frac 1 3 \int \frac {du}{u}= \frac 1 3 \ln(|u|)= \frac 1 3 \ln(\left|\sin(3x)\right|)$$

I hope it helps...

Comment: You need absolute value over the natural log.

Comment: @isham thanks, but i'm not understand the use of the ln, why is it necessary ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik true i just don't know the latex code for absolute value

Comment: @hjx  well because $\int \frac {dx} x =  \ln (x)$

Comment: @Isham I edited it for you.

Comment: @VivekKaushik thank you Vivek..

Comment: @hjx when you evaluate the derivative of $ln(x)$ you get $\frac 1 x$ and when you evaluate the integral of $ \frac 1 x$ you get the logarithm function.

Answer (score 1):

The $3x$ is of a hinder, so consider doing first $3x=t$, so the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{9}\int t\csc^2t\,dt
$$
You know that
$$
\int\csc^2t\,dt=-\cot t
$$
(the constant is irrelevant here) so integration by parts yields
$$
\int t\csc^2t\,dt=
t(-\cot t)-\int(-\cot t)\,dt=
-t\cot t+\int\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}\,dt=
-t\cot t+\ln\lvert\sin t\rvert+c
$$
Reinstating $t=3x$ and the factor $1/9$, you get
$$
\int x\csc^2(3x)\,dx=
-\frac{1}{3}x\cot3x+\frac{1}{9}\ln\lvert\sin 3x\rvert+c
$$